# htaccess infinite loop caused by redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to create a simple redirect however it is saying that it is caught in a inifite loop any ideas what I am doing wrong. I am wanting all requests from the root to a sub folder called quotemonkee.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / http://quotemonkee.co.uk/quotemonkee
```

Comment: Oh for god sake what is with people on these sites I explained what I am wanting to do gave an example and yet you critsise it plwse what is to complain about their

Comment: You are first enabling mod_rewrite, and then using mod_alias rule to do what you want to do. I suggest that you look up mod_rewrite way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Read the manual.

Answer (score 4):

Reading the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) really helps.

Redirect will match *everything that starts* with the URL path you specify. By using / that means everything. The result is that a request for `/quotemonkey` will also be matched and redirected to `/quotemonkey/quotemonkey` ad infinitum..

If you only want to redirect requests that use base domain try something like:

```
RedirectMatch /$ /quotemonkey
```